# Selenium window exception due to closed window

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In the past I have handled applications dealing with multiple windows. But the current application is a problem for me.

**Problem:**
The application gets launched in IE11 and it opens a new window. Before that,  it closes the parent window.

As the parent window is closed, the driver is not able to switch Windows.

I get NoSuchWindowException : unable to find element  on closed window.

**Question:**

How to deal with web driver window when the parent window is closed before launching new window?

**Note**:
 - The window stitching code works in other browsers except IE 11.
 - I have made Windows registry settings in my win 7 64 bit machine.
 - My tests should run only in IE 11.
 - Domain had been added in trusted zone.
 - trusted zone settings has been done.

*Question posted from mobile due to restrictions at work place.*

Comment: If launching window is closed and opens a new window, provide some explicit wait and switch to the only window handle in driver.getWindowHandles()

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. When the main window is not in scope, how could one deal with driver object?

Comment: .: **My understanding : main window[a]  is launched,after launching of window[a], new window[b] is launched but old window [a] is closed ,  Window [b] is launched by window [a]** If this is the case, it will maintain a single WindowHandle in driver...   Am I in sync?

Comment: Yes we are in same page. But the window handles are empty. Just wondering why...

Comment: can u share the code snippet?

Comment: Due to restrictions at my work place, I can't share the code. BTW SO is blocked too :)  posting this from mobile..

Comment: are you using 32 bit version of driverserver exe?

Comment: I have tried both 32 and 64 bit version of selenium IE driver 2.53.1